# Why Form_FormClosing event execute 2 times in c#.net

Tags: c#, events, backup, formclosing

I have a windows form application in C#.net and I want to backUp while closing the form by X button So I Wroted below code to do this action .but when I run the program I noticed that this event execute 2 times Please Help me to solve this problem

```
private void MenuFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //  DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("ایا مایل به گرفتن نسخه پشتیبان می باشید", "هشدار", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            //  if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes && !closefrm)
            try
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("آیا مایل به خروج از نرم افزار میباشید؟", "خروج", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    SaveFileDialog f = new SaveFileDialog();
                    f.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
                    f.Title = "HoghooghDastmozdBackup";
                    if (Directory.Exists("E:\\MobtakeranSoftBackup\\"))
                    {
                        f.FileName = "E:\\MobtakeranSoftBackup\\" + getPersianDate() + ".BAK";
                        f.FilterIndex = 1;
                        f.OverwritePrompt = true;
                        f.Filter = @"SQL Backup files (*.BAK) |*.BAK|All files(*.*) |*.*";
                        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
                        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE HoghooghDastmozd TO  DISK =@n", sqlconn);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", f.FileName);
                        sqlconn.Open();
                        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlconn.Close();
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\\MobtakeranSoftBackup\\");
                        f.FileName = "E:\\MobtakeranSoftBackup\\" + getPersianDate() + ".BAK";
                        f.FilterIndex = 1;
                        f.OverwritePrompt = true;
                        f.Filter = @"SQL Backup files (*.BAK) |*.BAK|All files(*.*) |*.*";
                        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
                        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE HoghooghDastmozd TO  DISK =@n", sqlconn);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", f.FileName);
                        sqlconn.Open();
                        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlconn.Close();
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Application.Exit();
            }


        }
```

Comment: Make sure you haven't got two event handlers wired up - search your project for "MenuFrm_FormClosing". You might want to check the CloseReason of the FormClosingEventArgs as well, as this will also fire when Windows is shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Application.Exit()`. This is done before the form has fully closed... it's still open. Thus, a new `Close` operation is triggered, which involves a second `Form_Closing` event. By the time you are able to process the second event, the first has finished and form is fully closed, and so it stops there (you end up with the event firing exactly twice, and not more).

You can adjust for this by adding a boolean to the class the defaults to false, check that it's false at the top of the method, and set it true at the end of the method. But that's just patching over the real problem... you're doing too much in the form_closing event. The `Application.Exit()` call belongs in `Form_Closed`, which would typically only fire once.

---

While I'm here, I want to point out this code:

```
sqlconn.Open();
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlconn.Close();
```

This is poor practice. The `.Close()` call for an SqlConnection object should **always** be in a `finally` block (the easiest way to accomplish that is via a `using` block). In this case you're probably okay, because the application is about to quit anyway, but it's just not a good habit to execute queries this way, and it make one wonder if the same mistake is made elsewhere in the program. I also wonder why you're repeating so much code here. That whole section can be reduced to this:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\\MobtakeranSoftBackup\\"); //it's good to just call this, even if the directory already exists.
f.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\MobtakeranSoftBackup", getPersianDate() + ".BAK");
f.FilterIndex = 1;
f.OverwritePrompt = true;
f.Filter = @"SQL Backup files (*.BAK) |*.BAK|All files(*.*) |*.*";
using (var sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring))
using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE HoghooghDastmozd TO  DISK =@n", sqlconn))
{
     sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", f.FileName);
      sqlconn.Open();
      sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: Joel Your code did not worked well.It Works like my code .it runs double time while closing the app.

Comment: Only the part above the horizontal line addresses your question. The rest is pointing out some obvious poor practice in the code.